# position Bootstrap brand next to navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I think the best would be I provide the website link which is : www.youthlife.de

I am trying to position the little brand logo closer to the navbar without changing the position of the navbar itself.

If I put a margin-left to the brand, the navbar moves as well. I don't get why. What regulates the distance between the brand and the navigation bar?

Comment: pls provide the codes that you already tried

Comment: Well i played around with margins and paddings and floats in developer tool. Just simple stuff, but the prob is the nav bar moves as well

Comment: can anyone help ?...

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using? and what's the size of your brand and logo?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what size of height and width of your logo.
Here's what I have tried.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=
"#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=""/>
 Start Bootstrap</a>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li> <a href="#">About</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Services</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.navbar-brand img {
    width:90px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-3px;
}
```

You can check the demo **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Alicera/dzdmj317/)**.

Now, let me know further if it is not what you wish.
Hint: Pls provide some codes to see what's been wrong with it.